# How to fix Odoo server that is constantly showing popup of "Connection Lost" and "Connection Restored" and also kept being disconnected?

Tags: ubuntu, odoo, openerp

I'm currently using Odoo 12.0+e-20181025. At first, we didn't have that problem, but lately it has become more and more unstable. When it happened, I and my users can't connect to Odoo. I tried checking the connection to the server and found it was normal and stable. But we can't connect to Odoo application for a few minutes. Even after I restarted the server, it kept going like that. Only after a few minutes (between 7-12 minutes) it will return to normal again and usually will keep being normal throughout the day. But these couple of days, it started to happen more and more often.

Is this normal and does anyone have a way to fix this? My users workload is quite big and we can't be having this interruption. Some has said that I need to look at the error log but there is no log file in the server so far.

Thanks for reading and for the help.